# sending mail from docker container

Tags: docker, sendmail

I have a docker container running debian buster with docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe. In that container I install sendmail and I do `yes yes | sendmailconfig' and I can send mail just fine.

I have another container running CentOS 7 with docker version 17.06.2-ee-3, build 915cbaa. There does not seem to be sendmailconfig in CentOS 7 so in that I do 'm4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` and when I try and send mail it fails with:

```
larry.martll@gmail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
larry.martll@gmail.com... Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

Anyone know how I can configure sendmail in the latter case so that I can send mail?

Comment: did you restart the service after the change?

Comment: That was a long time ago - I don’t even work at the same job any more.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to postfix and was able to get this working.